# Automating Application installation in Mac

Tags: applescript

I want to Automate the process of Installing the software which is downloaded and saved in some location. Pls explain me how to automate this process thru Applescript

Comment: Do you mean just automating the process of extracting archives or running installers in general? If so, see [this question at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/259132/how-could-you-automate-downloading-and-installing-os-x-applications).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a developer makes a disk image, a .dmg file using "Disk Utility.app" and then either:

- Have an alias to the Application folder and has the end-user drag and drop from the disk image into the Application folder.

or

- Have a disk image or some other means of delivering the executable and has an installer made with Apple's "PackageMaker.app" application.  PackageMaker.app isn't distributed with Apple's Developer Tools anymore (inside of XCode.app) rather, PackageMaker.app is a separate download, available at the following URL.

Using PackageMaker.app is the preferred way of developing an installer since it's what users are used to and has a number of features that make it easier to develop an installer than developing one from scratch:

Link to Apple's Developer Tools:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

Use the above link and then search for "PackageMaker" (with no space) and take the most recent version available.